# Locating data from a previous record

Tags: ms-access

No code at the moment but have tried DLookup but I couldn’t fathom it out.
I have a closing stock amount of fuel in tanks at the end of the day. 
In my database I have a form/table for fuel amounts and when I press the command button for a new amount to be entered I need the previous days closing amount to become the new records opening amount.
Eg

```
 1/1/19 Open amount =38000
  Sales = 1000
  1/1/19 Close amount = 37000
```

I would then press new dip amount for 2/1/19 and I would like the Open amount to be 37000 which is the previous days close amount.
I would be great full if anyone could help.

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *DLookup*:

```
OpenAmount = DLookup("[Close amount]", "[YourTable]", "[YourDateField] = DateAdd('d', -1, Date())")
```